# Concept of Booth Encoded Multiplier 8bit

Tags: encoder, multiplier, carry-look-ahead

So I'm kinda a newbie in this world so pardon me for the basic questions.

I want to implement Booth encoded multiplier 8bit. Until now, I pretty much understand for the block diagram and what happened inside that block that there's still some problem that I'm not sure.
[image]

1. Is it will be a different structure between signed and unsigned multiplier ?
2. On the Partial Product Generator, what do variables N0-N3 mean and how to calculate it?
3. What is the purpose of padding 1 on the partial product ?
4. For the Adder Part, I'm going to use CSA and the final adder using CLA just like the pictures. But I'm not sure if I need to align the 3 partial product or not ?
   [image]

It would be great if anyone can explain to me, or maybe if there's any good resources/references to be read. Because I can't find the complete explanation for the whole process.

Comment: Have you looked at Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm

Comment: Good resources which I used in the past effectively for Booth algorithm: Google, YouTube.